# IIS error after Windows update

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

A Windows 2003 update messed up my server bad, so I had to reinstall .net v2. Now I can't access any .aspx pages (html load fine). When I try, I get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace..ctor(System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceSourceKind,
>   System.String, System.String)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.MethodAccessException:
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace..ctor(System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceSourceKind,
>   System.String, System.String)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MethodAccessException:
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace..ctor(System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceSourceKind,
>   System.String, System.String)]
>   System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility.InitDiagnosticTraceImpl(TraceSourceKind
>   sourceType, String traceSourceName) +0
>   System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility.InitializeTracing()
>   +13    System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility..cctor()
>   +89
>
> [TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for
>   'System.ServiceModel.DiagnosticUtility'
>   threw an exception.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(ContextInformation
>   evalContext, String sectionPath) +116 
>   System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceHostingEnvironmentSection.UnsafeGetSection()
>   +33    System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.LoadConfigParameters()
>   +30    System.ServiceModel.HostingManager..ctor()
>   +112    System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureInitialized()
>   +160    System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.OnEnsureInitialized(Object
>   state) +5
>   System.ServiceModel.PartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state) +84
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +103
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +157    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +65
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.1873;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.1433

Comment: @user Someone on Google got it to work by re-installing IIS. But you should take a hint from the close votes. :)

Comment: Serverfault will be a better place for this. You will also want to post more details about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need some more information to try and resolve this any further, but I would suggest you need to run [the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) after installing asp.net

Comment: I had already tried aspnet_regiis -i, but it didnt help...